# Apache startup is failed

Tags: apache-2.2, suexec

My server was terminated abnormally because power was turned off.
After start server I can't to run Apache.

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [FAILED]
```

Apache log file:

[notice] suexec mechanism enabled (wrapper /usr/sbin/suexec)

```
$ ll /usr/sbin/suexec
-rws--x--x 1 root apache 11544 Nov 12 2008 /usr/sbin/suexec
```

I was tryed to run suexec:

```
suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

SUEXEC log file:

```
too few arguments
```

Сan anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

UPD:

```
$ suexec -V
-D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
-D AP_GID_MIN=100
-D AP_HTTPD_USER="apache"
-D AP_AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/httpd/suexec.log"
-D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
-D AP_UID_MIN=500
-D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```

OS: Redhat Linux 2.6.18-128el15

Apache 2.2.3

Comment: What about `suexec -V`?

Comment: What changed? Do you always reboot your server after software upgrades/reconfigurations to make sure they still boot? What OS and Distro is this? What version of Apache?

Comment: No changes was @ChrisS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing `ssl.conf` from an included config files to `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ssl.conf was misconfigured. So i renamed ssl.conf to ssl.conf.old and create a default ssl.conf file again and copied the default contents.

Default contents can be copied from https://serverfault.com/a/474467/274486

or http://www.techrappers.com/post/13117/apache-webserver-fails-start-suexec-mechanism-enabled

After that i tried to restart Apache and it worked like a charm!

This post put me to right direction:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000065589-Apache-webserver-fails-to-start-suEXEC-mechanism-enabled